Webhooks: Persist client registration
I am new to Webhooks in C#.
I am writing a server and would like to persist client registrations between sessions, rather than use in-memory registration.
Ideally, this would be by using a file on the local disk, to contain the details of the clients.
I've probably spent 3 days googling this, but cannot find a single code example (or any decent documentation) on how to do this.
Everything seems to point back to this article:
https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-Asp.Net-WebHooks
Which I do not find helpful.
My starting point was this excellent introduction:
https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-Asp.Net-WebHooks
However, this does not cover persisted registration.
Thank you.
